# For Loop in Python POST Method

Tags: python, json, loops, post, flask

I'm trying to load a form again and again by submitting, until the counter is at **n** (e.g. 3, see graphic). Because I'm pretty new in python I cannot handle the for loops and the counters right. Do you have any suggestions or ideas how I can implement this correctly?
[image]

**Thank you very much in advance.**

```
@app.route('/accounts/test/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def accounts_test_login():

if request.method == 'POST':
    word =  request.form['character']
    scribble_normalized = pd.DataFrame(normalize(json.loads(request.form['output1'])))
    saved = load_scribbles_for_user(word)
    result = similarity(scribble_normalized, saved)
    session['scores'] = []

    if result:
        sumSessionCounter()
        session['scores'].extend([word, True])
        if session['counter'] >= 5:
            session['counter'] = 0
            return render_template('accounts/test/failure.html', word=word, output=scribble_normalized,
                        errors=scores)
        return render_template('accounts/test/medium.html', word=word, output=scribble_normalized)


    else:
        sumSessionCounter()
        session['scores'].extend([word, False])
        if session['counter'] >= 5:
            session['counter'] = 0
            return render_template('accounts/test/failure.html', word=word, output=scribble_normalized,
                        errors=session['scores'])
        return render_template('accounts/test/medium.html', word=word, output=scribble_normalized)
```

and here is the function sumSessionCounter

```
def sumSessionCounter():
try:
session['counter'] += 1
except KeyError:
session['counter'] = 1
```

Comment: everytime blowser `POST` page to server then server calls `accounts_test_login` again and it sets `counter = 0`. You have to save `counter` in `session` or `databas`e or use it in `url` ie. `accounts/test/medium.html?count=some_value` to keed this value.

Answer (score 1):

As furas suggested in his comment, you could store the counter in the session or perhaps a database.  You could also store it as a hidden input field on the form.

In your template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="counter" value="{{ counter }}">
```

In your view:

```
counter = request.form.get('counter', type=int) or 0


return render_template('accounts/test/medium.html', word=word, output=scribble_normalized, counter=counter+1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin and Furas!
I updated now my code with "session['counter'] and it works much better. It stops as soon as it counts to 5 and returns another template. But now I have the problem that if a few people test the application at same time, the counter will keep it same for everyone and not individual. That shouldn't be the case, do you have any further suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: Session values are stored in a cookie.  Those are specific to each user, so you should not encounter that issue.

Comment: Thanks very much Kevin, I appreciate that a lot! 
Could you maybe also help me with the array that I'm trying to set up. (see updated code). The array always overwrites with the newest entity, I'm doing something wrong. The array should always store the results and show it on the final page.